# Flex element inside another flex element collapses on Safari

Tags: html, css, flexbox, safari

I got this code working on Chrome where the content of first **flex-item** needs to be aligned to the bottom and stretches if necessary:

```css
body {
  height:100vh;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.flex-stretch {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item flex-stretch">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">3</div>
</div>
```

but on Safari it doesn't respect the content of the first **flex-item** and collapses if the viewport is smaller than the **flex-container** and scrolling is necessary.

**Is there any work around this issue?**

Thanks, this is my first question here :)

Here is the codePen: https://codepen.io/felphos/pen/GRZVKwY

Comment: You've set `flex-shrink` to 1 in the `flex-stretch` class styles. Try `flex: 1 0 auto` or give it a `min-height` which it shouldn't shrink below.

Comment: I can't set the min-height because it depends on the content of that div and I also need that div to shrink or grow according to the space left. If you run the code snippet and click on full page you can see the desired behaviour when there is room for the div to grow, in Chrome obviously :)

Comment: I "solved" it using JavaScript where I have a div with the content inside of the .flex-stretch div and if the height of that div is >= to the height of the .flex-stretch div I change the display of the .flex-stretch to block instead of flex. It's quite ok for now but I'd love to solve it via CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use flexbox you shouldn't define the height explicitly. I think that removing `height: "100%"` and also setting `.flex-stretch{flex: 1 0 auto;}` (0 flex-shrink) will get you what you want.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I need!